# How to add buttons into <td /> inside a dynamic table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I want to add a button to my dynamic table which is fetching data from an API. It fetches the data based on the header id in the JSON data. The header id that I want to display button is called actions.
This is my code for :

```
<tbody>
  {data.map((row, index) => (
    <tr key={index}>
      {headers.map((header, i) => {
        return <td key={i}>{row[header.id]}</td>;
      })}
    </tr>
  ))}
</tbody>
```

I want to display buttons like the following:

[image: img1]

I am new to ReactJS and this is what I tried:

```
<tbody>
  {data.map((row, index) => (
    <tr key={index}>
      {headers.map((header, i) => {
        if (header.id === actions) {
          return (
            <td key={i}>
              <button>Edit</button>
            </td>
          );
        } else {
          return <td key={i}>{row[header.id]}</td>;
        }
      })}
    </tr>
  ))}
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to add a renderer option in headers so you can add a custom field (it's similar to how DataGrid on MUI handle this case using renderCell):

```
<tbody>
  {data.map((row, index) => (
    <tr key={index}>
      {headers.map((header, i) => (
         <td key={i}>{headers.renderer ? headers.renderer(row) : row[row.id]}</td>
      ))}
    </tr>
  ))}
</tbody>
```

The headers will look something like that:

```
const headers = [
    {
        label: "Name", 
        id: "name"
    },
    {
        label: "Age",
        id: "age"
    },
    {
        label: "Actions",
        renderer: (row)=>{
            return (
                <Fragment>
                    <button onClick={()=>handleEdit(row)}>Edit</button>
                    <button onClick={()=>handleRemove(row)}>Remove</button>
                </Fragment>
            );
        }
    }
];
```

Comment: Change "id" to "field", field make sense more than id. Another thing is it's recommended to declare renderer in other file (name it renderers or whatever you want) then you can import it, just to keep the code clear.